# Best model type in TensorFlow.js for Color Prediction?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow.js

I was creating a color predictor when I realized a problem arise. I got the model to work successfully, but the predictions are always within the same median range of about 2.5 to about 5.5. The model is supposed to output a 0 thru 8 corresponding to each color, and I have an even amount of data point for each color for training. Is there a better model I can use so that it will predict something to be 0 or 7? I'm assuming it won't because it thinks they are some kind of outliers.

Here's my model

```
const model = tf.sequential();

const hidden = tf.layers.dense({
  units: 3,
  inputShape: [3] //Each input has 3 values r, g, and b
});
const output = tf.layers.dense({
  units: 1 //only one output (the color that corresponds to the rgb values
    });
model.add(hidden);
model.add(output);

model.compile({
  activation: 'sigmoid',
  loss: "meanSquaredError",
  optimizer: tf.train.sgd(0.005)
});
```

Is this a good model for my problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO; i kindly suggest to edit your question, remove the storytelling & the redundant info (it just creates clutter, lowering the chances of getting an answer), and clarify *precisely* and *succinctly* what *exactly* is your issue (as it stands, it's quite unclear). Be sure to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: why don't you create a balanced dataset for each color? for example, 100 data points for each class. i think you are facing class imbalance issue.

Comment: @sjishan I spent time to get 20 data points for every single color, and the problem still happens, still never leaves that median range, good suggestion tho, I would get to 100 on all data points but waiting to have some of the colors be randomly generated 100 times is pretty dang rare

Comment: @desertnaut Thanks for the tip! I tried to cut out the background information and only tried to keep mostly what will solve my problem

Comment: Does the output need to be an integer from the range 1 to 8? Because if that is the case, you're using regression for a classification problem. Also, you can add non-linearity to the model.

Comment: @edkeveked yes preferably, each one indicating a color. I see what you are saying, the inputs are not linearly indicative to the outputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model is lacking non-linearity, for there is no activation functions.
Given a rgb input, the model should predict the most likely color in 8 possible values. It is a classification problem. The model as defined in the question is doing a regression, i.e it is trying to predict a numerical value given the input.

For classification problem, the last layer should predict probabilities. `softmax` activation function is mostly used for the last layer in that case. 
The loss function should be `categoricalCrossentropy` or `binaryCrossEntropy` (if there were only two colors to predict).

Consider the following model predicting 3 classes of colors: red, green and blue

```js
const model = tf.sequential();
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 10, inputShape: [3], activation: 'sigmoid' }));
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 10, activation: 'sigmoid' }));
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 3, activation: 'softmax' }));

model.compile({ loss: 'categoricalCrossentropy', optimizer: 'adam' });

const xs = tf.tensor([
  [255, 23, 34],
  [255, 23, 43],
  [12, 255, 56],
  [13, 255, 56],
  [12, 23, 255],
  [12, 56, 255]
]);

// Labels
const label = ['red', 'red', 'green', 'green', 'blue', 'blue']
const setLabel = Array.from(new Set(label))
const ys = tf.oneHot(tf.tensor1d(label.map((a) => setLabel.findIndex(e => e === a)), 'int32'), 3)

// Train the model using the data.
  model.fit(xs, ys, {epochs: 100}).then((loss) => {
  const t = model.predict(xs);
  pred = t.argMax(1).dataSync(); // get the class of highest probability
  labelsPred = Array.from(pred).map(e => setLabel[e])
  console.log(labelsPred)
}).catch((e) => {
  console.log(e.message);
})
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.13.3/dist/tf.min.js"> </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks! I see now, the idea is to get a probability for each color, then choose the highest probability, I understand now. But I have to ask, what lead you to made 2 hidden layers with 10 nodes?

Comment: For the number of layers and how many nodes for each layer, you can iterate until you find one that leads to better accuracy. There is no general formula for it.